# Kibana: type with multiple fields

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Does Kibana support types with multiple fields, for e.g a distance type haveing fields like km,miles etc. Basically [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/_multi_fields.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  As with the example you posted, kibana can graph use those fields.  People use myField.raw for aggregation and labeling, which is often much better than myField.

So, myField.km, if populated, should work just fine.

You might also look at kibana's [scripting feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-fields.html#create-scripted-field), which would allow you to store one version and compute the other when displayed.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, Kibana does not support Nested Json.
You need to change it to standard Json